# react testing library - text is being found in element but not as expected

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing a tic-tac-toe game with the following two components:

`GameBoard` handles the graphic representation:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { clsx } from 'clsx';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


interface Props {
    moves?: [number,number][];
    handleMove: () => void;
};

type Mark = '' | 'X' | 'O';

const Row = ({row, rIndex, handleMove}) => {

    return row?.map((col,cIndex) => <div key={col.toString() + cIndex} onClick={()=>handleMove(rIndex,cIndex)} data-testid="square" style={{border: "1px solid grey", borderRadius: "10px", display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", height: '200px', fontSize: "50px"}}>{col}</div>);
};

const GameBoard = ({
    moves = [],
    handleMove
}:Props) => {

    const [sideLength, setSideLength] = useState(3); // sidelength is set in gameboard because the logic for determining if a player has won is independent of it
    const cols = Array(sideLength).fill('');
    const rows = cols.map(col => Array(sideLength).fill(col.slice()));

    for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++){
        const [y,x] = moves[i];
        const mark:Mark = i % 2 === 0 ? 'X' : 'O';
        rows[y][x] = mark;
    }

    return (
        <div className="game-board" style={{display:"grid", gridGap: "1%", gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${sideLength}, 1fr)`, gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${sideLength}, 1fr)`, padding: "20%", paddingTop: "0"}}>
            { rows.map((row, index) => <Row key={row.toString() + index} row={row} rIndex={index} handleMove={handleMove} />)}
        </div>
    );
};


export default GameBoard;
```

`TicTacToe` mostly handles the game logic

```
import {useState} from "react";
import GameBoard from "./GameBoard";
const TicTacToe = () => {

    const [winner,setWinner] = useState(null)
    const [moves,setMoves] = useState<number[][]>([]);
    const handleMove = (rIndex,cIndex) => {
        setMoves((old) => {
            return [...old, [rIndex,cIndex]];
        });
    };

    return (<div>
        <GameBoard moves={moves} handleMove={handleMove}  />
    </div>)

};

export default TicTacToe;
```

When I test it in the browser, clicking squares alternately adds "X"s and "O"s as expected.  But in the following test, I can't confirm this:

```
test("symbols alternate on moves", ()=>{
    render(<TicTacToe />);

    const beforeSquares = screen.getAllByTestId('square');
    const beforeOne = beforeSquares[0]; // X
    const beforeTwo = beforeSquares[1]; // O
    const beforeThree = beforeSquares[2]; // X

    
    userEvent.click(beforeOne);
    userEvent.click(beforeTwo);
    userEvent.click(beforeThree);

    const afterSquares = screen.getAllByTestId('square');
    const afterOne = afterSquares[0]; // X
    const afterTwo = afterSquares[1]; // O
    const afterThree = afterSquares[2]; // X

    waitFor(()=>{
        expect(afterOne).toHaveTextContent('X');  // test also passes if I change this to 'Z'
        expect(afterTwo).toHaveTextContent('O');
        expect(afterThree).toHaveTextContent('X');
    });

});
```

As indicated in the comments, the `expect` with `X` anywhere on the screen finds something -- an element with `data-testid` of `square`, but when I query for these elements and check their `textContent`, they are all empty!  Why isn't this working for me?

Comment: Try doing another `const squares = screen.getAllByTestId('square');` after your await.

Comment: @possum. I used `let` because I can't redeclare a constant, and it seems to work.  But isn't there a better way to write this?  Feels like I shouldn't have to keep redeclaring the variables.

Comment: Call it something else.  You're not "redeclaring variables", if that works it's likely because you're requesting new elements from a new state not reflected in your old ones.

Comment: @possum I think there's another problem with my test approach.  I tried your suggestion and created two sets of variables for comparison.  My `expect` statements in the `waitFor` (see updated code) seem to be broken - they also work when I expect something that isn't there.